# How do I bin my numeric data in to a categorical variable with two levels

Tags: r

I currently have a numeric column (grassland$numberseen) with a wide range of numeric data from 0 to 3000, but I want to turn this in to a  new categorical variable with two levels: present (number  > 0) and absent (number seen = 0). How do I create this?

Comment: You can use a `logical` vector, `bin <- (mynum > 0)`. If you need that to be an integer (not logical), then `+(mynum > 0)` (the plus sign). If you need more than two levels, look up the [`?cut`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html) function for 2 or more levels.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe the code should be grassland$CategoricalNumbersseen <- +(grassland$numberseen) and this has created a series of 1's and 0's. But how do I make this so the 1s are in one category called present and 0s are in another called absence?

Comment: You can still use the `cut` function.

Comment: It might help if you provide a more reproducible question, including basic sample data (perhaps just `data.frame(...)`), any code you've tried, and what your intended output is (perhaps as another `data.frame`).

Comment: I have done it now thank you, I used your answer and the cut function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(grassland,
  new_variable = ifelse(numberseen > 0, 1, 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `base R`

```
grassland$new_variable <- +(grassland$numberseen >0)
```